# Repetitions and Set Identity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A set consisting only of an infinite list of a repeating constant is finite. For example:

> $\{1, 1, 1, \dots\} = \{1\}$

My question, which I suspect is rather stupid, is whether there is not a mathematically interesting sense in which the left set is bigger than the right one?

*As* sets they're identical (due to extensionality?), so in a set theory with nothing but sets, the answer is obvious. I wonder, however, if there may be theories either without extensionality or with urelements that would be able to distinguish between the two (it is, of course, questionable whether the two *should* be distinguished).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these objects are called [Multisets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).

Multistets $\{1,1,1\}$ and $\{1\}$ are different multisets.

In fact a multiset M can be seen as set of the form $A\times\mathbb Z^+$ where $A $ if $(a,b)\in M$ then the element $a$ is found $b$ times in $M$.